# show tooltip for each point of highcharts network graph in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am building networkgraphs using highcharts and highcharts-angular on my Angular application. I am able to display the graph with datalabels successfully. Now, I have to show some tooltip data when I hover on each point/node of the graph. How can I do it? How can I show a tooltip corresponding to each point of the graph?

As of now, I am using the below options to draw the graph and show the tooltip. This tooltip, is showing same information when I hover any point. I need to show a different data for each point. How can I do it?

```
chartOptions = {
"chart": {
    "type": "networkgraph",
    "height": "100%"      
},
"title": {
    "text": "Network graph demo"
},
"subtitle": {
    "text": "A Force-Directed Network Graph in Highcharts"
},
"plotOptions": {
    "networkgraph": {
    "keys": ["from", "to"],
    "layoutAlgorithm": {
        "enableSimulation":true
    }
    }

},
"series": [
    {
    "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,            
        "linkFormat": ""          
    },
    "data": [{"from" : "a", "to": "b"},
            {"from": "a", "to": "c"},
            {"from": "a", "to": "d"} ],
    "marker" : {"radius" : 18}
    }

],
"tooltip" :
{
    "enabled" : true, 
    "formatter" : function() {
    return "<div> <span> My tooltip information </span> </div>"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `console.log()` to explore the objects available to me within the Highcharts API

You'll see in the console output all the accessible information, within which `name` seems to be what you're after?

Try this:

```
"tooltip" :
{
    "enabled" : true, 
    "formatter" : function() {
        console.log(this.point)
      return this.point.name
    }
}
```

Update below, is this close to what you're after?

```
"tooltip" :
{
    "enabled" : true, 
    "useHTML" : true, 
    "formatter" : function() {
      let linkFrom_li = '';
      let linkTo_li   = '';
      let tooltipHTML   = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < this.point.linksTo.length; i++) {
          linkFrom_li = linkFrom_li + `<li>${this.point.linksTo[i].from}</li>`;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < this.point.linksFrom.length; i++) {
          linkTo_li   = linkTo_li + `<li>${this.point.linksFrom[i].to}</li>`;
      }
      tooltipHTML = tooltipHTML + `<b>Links from [${this.point.name}]</b>:<ul>${linkFrom_li}</ul>`;
      tooltipHTML = tooltipHTML + `<b>Links to [${this.point.name}]</b>:<ul>${linkTo_li}</ul>`;
      return tooltipHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I already tried that. By default this.point.name is actually showing the same tooltip value as label. I want to show a different description. How can I show it? What parameter, I have to use it?

Comment: @Sreehari, answer updated. The tooltip is now much different than the `label` attribute would show.

Comment: Yes, this answer has given me some way forward to implement scenario.

Comment: @Sreehari   If it deserves it, please award the answer a pretty green check mark?